# PHP view in datagrid

Tags: php, xml

Does php has datagridview object or something? Or do I just make a table out of it? I need to do this format, http://replays.mineski.net/.. Do you think XML as a information storage is suitable for this?

Comment: PHP does not have any UI objects built in. You can create an HTML table from any tabular data; it need not be stored in any particular way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, html table is itself some kind of datagrid. So just use html table, tr, td to achieve what you want, additionally, use th for table headers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like PEAR datagrid http://pear.php.net/package/Structures_DataGrid, there are also some nice javascript based ones you can use eg: http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx